# Can we execute Mdx queries on MySql database directly.If yes how?

Tags: mysql, analytics, mdx, pentaho

I want use MDX queries directly against MySQL database. Right now I am using Pentaho's MIS analytics to run the MDX queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute MDX Queries on DB, but the related SQL query can be executed, for that to happen you will have Enable Mondrian Logs in Pentaho. So that it will generate the SQL Query for that particular MDX Query.

Please follow the steps:

1. Go to `\pentaho\WEB-INF\classes`.
2. Edit. Enable all the logs in Log4j File.
3. Enable the following Tags:

   ```
   MONDRIAN
   MDXLOG
   SQLLOG
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect the answer is no.

You execute `MDX` against a multi-dimensional structure - `MySQL` database is relational.

You need to store the data in a multi-dimensional format first - then `mdx` may be possible.